# Getting Error while adding data in sqlite3 database using Flask

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to add data in the existing database but getting error output, There is a minor mistake please help me.Thanks

Code ::

```
@app.route('/')
def new_student():
    return render_template('student.html')

@app.route('/addrec', methods=['POST', 'GET'])

def addrec():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            nm = request.form['nm']
            addr = request.form['add']
            city = request.form['city']
            pin = request.form['pin']

            with sql.connect("database.db") as con:
                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.execute('''INSERT INTO students (name,addr,city,pin)
                    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)''',(nm,addr,city,pin))

                con.commit()
                msg = "Record successfully added"
        except:

            con.rollback()
            msg = "error in insert operation"

        finally:
            return render_template("result.html", msg=msg)
            con.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My result.html file is :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>
      result of addition : {{ msg }}
      <h2><a href = "\">go back to home page</a></h2>
   </body>
</html>
```

The output should be:: "Record successfully added" but I am getting an "error in the insert operation".

Comment: Can you remove the try/except and show us the traceback you get when you try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have a typo in your code:

```
addr = request.form['add']
```

should be

```
addr = request.form['addr']
```

But your code needs some fixes regarding the connection:

`con.commit()` is called on normal exit of the `with` block, and `con.rollback()` is called if the `with` block is exited because of an exception (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager)). You don't need those two explicit calls.

Furthermore, you placed the `con.close()` after the `return` statement, which means it will never be executed. Just swap the lines, or consider opening the connection at the start of the program.

Comment: Thanks Buddy ,there was minor error i have corrected as you have suggested ,

Answer (score 0):

After the `except:`, put a `raise` to re-raise the last exception and post here the traceback.

Possible problems are:

- You don't have permission on database.db file
- You didn't send one of the form keys and accessing `request.form["some key"]` is raising KeyError exception.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with this for many hours. First, you need to create a python file and run it to create a database. After that run the main python file. It worked for me. No need to change "add" to "addr", because in student.html, name is given as "add"
Also create a home.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<HTML>  
<head>  
     <title>home</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
   <h2>Hi, welcome to the website</h2>  
   <a href="/enternew">Add New Record</a><br><be>  
   <a href ="/list">Show List</a><br><be>  
</body>  
</html>
```